# Who's the cron worker?

Tags: cron

If I set cron job for a normal user instead of root, what account execute the scheduled jobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user you added the cron job as.

Comment: Though... were *do* you set the cron job?  If it's in /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.d, you **have to** specify the user it runs as explicitly.  But then you'd know, so Ignacio's answer is probably fully on the mark.

Answer (score 3):

Cron jobs in /etc/crontab and /etc/cron.d/ run as the user specified in the extra username field.
Cron jobs in files in /var/spool/crontab/ (or your distro's equivalent) run as the user who inserted that crontab, usually the user for whom the file is named.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X and I did edit with `crontab -e`. How do you think in my case?

Comment: the crontab application modifies the user's crontab file in /var/spool/crontab (not sure about the OSX equivalent), and thus runs as the user.